# How to use shared preferences for Flutter 2.0 WIndows Desktop? Or is there any other library same as shared pref for Flutter Windows desktop

Tags: windows, flutter, sharedpreferences, desktop

I have been using Flutter for a while now. I am just trying to develop a Flutter Windows application recently. While I have shared preferences for flutter mobile app, there seems no alternative for Flutter Windows desktop application. Is there a way to use share pref in desktop application? Or is there any other library for the same purpose which support flutter windows desktop?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences - they say that the following platforms are supported: `ANDROID IOS LINUX MACOS WEB WINDOWS`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin, or [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)

Comment: Don't use Hive on Windows if you want multiple instances of your app. First instance locks the files, then second just hangs there because it can not access the files.